# Domain redirection to Azure subscription

Tags: azure

I have one website running under current domain domain1.com which is not azure site. we build a new application with the new azure subscription

I wanted to redirect/host the domain1.com to my azure subscription. how can we achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure a new custom domain for you Azure Web App. You can follow the tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have the custom domain pointing to my physical web server. now we decommission the server and hence we want to own the same domain to my windows azure account through set up VM. how can we get this?

Comment: If you want to associated your domain to a VM running on a Cloud Service you need to create a CNAME registry pointing to yout http://xxxx.cloudapp.net domain. Here is the documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/